# IEEEtran: \ref works but \cref does not

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ieeetran, cleveref

So I am using the `IEEEtran` document class for the first time and I have a problem. When I cross-reference a figure/table/section/whatever with `\ref` I get the expected reference number. But I would like to automatically insert the associated prefix -- Figure, Section, whatever -- which can be done with the package `cleveref`. However, when I use the `\cref` command, I get the output `??` in the pdf document.

My preamble is like this

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first 
% footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

One of my figures is defined like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{graphs/full_vector_gen_8.eps}
  \caption{Experiment results for the Full Vector algorithm with generation size 8.}
  \label{fig:res-fv-gen-8}
\end{figure}
```

And the `\cref` command is `\cref{fig:res-fv-gen-8}` for instance. None of my `\cref` commands work.

EDIT: 
Noticed that I get this warning:
`LaTeX Warning: Reference 'fig:res-fv-gen-8' on page 1 undefined on input line 3.`

Comment: `cleveref` must always be loaded *after* `hyperref`. No exceptions.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mico and yes it is a duplicate then. I thought it was a problem with IEEETran and thanks for the edit :)